# Как можно перевести const char в const wchar_t

Tags: c++, char, const

Как можно перевести const char в const wchar_t? уже много сайтов облазил, так и не нашел, ответа...

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "tlhelp32.h"

#define dllx extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// find is process processName running?

bool _IsProcessRun( const char * processName )
{
   HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );

   PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
   pe.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );
   Process32First( hSnapshot, &pe );

   while( true ) {
       if( wcscpy( pe.szExeFile, processName ) == 0 ) return true;
       if( !Process32Next( hSnapshot, &pe ) ) return false;
   }
}

// return value to gml
dllx double IsProcessRun( char *process )
{
    return (int) _IsProcessRun( process );
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30409491/5006740

Comment: А не нужно ли в данной функции вместо `wcscpy` использовать `wcscmp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно использовать [mbstowcs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbstowcs/)
В коде это будет примерно так

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cwchar>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

std::wstring to_wstring(const char* str) {
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> tmp = nullptr;
    size_t sz, len;
    len = mbstowcs(nullptr, str, 0); // получить размер
    sz = len + 1;
    tmp.reset(new wchar_t[sz]);      // выделить память
    mbstowcs(tmp.get(), str, sz);    // перекодировать
    return std::wstring(tmp.get());
}
std::wstring to_wstring(const std::string& str) {
    return to_wstring(str.c_str());
}

bool _IsProcessRun( const char * processName )
{
   HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );

   PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
   pe.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );
   Process32First( hSnapshot, &pe );
   std::wstring name = to_wstring(processName);

   while( Process32Next( hSnapshot, &pe ) ) {
       if( name == pe.szExeFile ) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: в итоге получился этот код:
https://pp.vk.me/c633417/v633417732/2c4e2/p6qyFNusOMo.jpg
и эти прекрасные сообщения красного цвета
https://pp.vk.me/c633417/v633417732/2c4da/PqQ9Qud2DN8.jpg

Comment: или все таки что то не так?..

Comment: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` нужно добавлять перед _всеми_ `#include` в файле `stdafx.h`

Comment: Переработал вашу функцию поиска процесса

Comment: @SweetCelestia Лучше действительно использовать `mbstowcs_s` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstowcs), как минимум, если предстоит работа в многопоточном окружении: `mbstowcs` хранит состояниие и будет забавным вызывать её из разных функций и из разных потоков. Либо использовать `mbsrtowcs` - в нём состояние хранится снаружи и вы его контролируете.